# Building a uwsgi plugin for python 3.9 failed for older version it works. Are there any other options?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, uwsgi, python-3.9

i downloaded the latest source code `uwsgi-2.0.19.1` and tried to build a uwsgi plugin
for `python 3.9` but it failed every time. For other Versions like `python3.6` or `python3.8` it works and i used them in other Django Projects. For Example...

**Here it works:**

---

Command:

```
[user@me /uwsgi-2.0.19.1] $ make PROFILE=nolang

[user@me /uwsgi-2.0.19.1] $ PYTHON=python3.6 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python36"
```

Output:

```
*** uWSGI building and linking plugin from plugins/python ***
[gcc -pthread] python36_plugin.so
build time: 5 seconds
*** python36 plugin built and available in python36_plugin.so ***
```

Command:

```
[user@me /uwsgi-2.0.19.1] $ PYTHON=python3.8 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python38"
```

Output:

```
*** uWSGI building and linking plugin from plugins/python ***
[gcc -pthread] python38_plugin.so
build time: 5 seconds
*** python38 plugin built and available in python38_plugin.so ***
```

**Here it fails:**

---

"Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden" is german and means "File or directory not found".

command:

```
[user@me /uwsgi-2.0.19.1] $ PYTHON=python3.9 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python39"
```

outpu:

```
*** uWSGI building and linking plugin from plugins/python ***
[gcc -pthread] python39_plugin.so
In file included from plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/pyutils.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/pyloader.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/wsgi_headers.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/web3_subhandler.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/pump_subhandler.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/gil.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/profiler.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/symimporter.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/tracebacker.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/raw.c:1:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    2 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
*** unable to build python39 plugin ***
```

---

**Question:**

---

- Does it mean `python3.9` is not supported? Could not find anything in the `uWSGI` docs, maybe i missed it.
- Can i download somewhere a already build plugin for `python3.9` ? I am not allowed to `sudo apt install` anything because i am on a shared Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. So my suspicion was right  `uwsgi-2.0.19.1` Version did not supported `python 3.9`. With the latest or newer `uwsgi` Versions i could create a plugin for `python 3.9`.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps someone else that comes along a similar issue.
my problem was uwsgi using always python3.8 when i wanted it to use python3.9 (apt installs and pip3, etc. nothing worked, i couldn't get the python3.9 plugin for uwsgi)

my solution was to install python3.9-dev

`$ sudo apt install python3.9-dev`

instead of just 'python3.9'

then `$ python3 -m pip uninstall uwsgi`

and finally `$ python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir uwsgi`

this apparently included the uwsgi python3.9 plugin required, while ensuring that i removed any cached python3.8 stuff in apt
glhf!